# how to save python Dynamic code to database with proper indentation(formatted style)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Consider Following code

```
result = []
for i in range(1,11):
  if i%2 == 0:
    result.append("Even")
  else:
    result.append("Odd")
print(result)
```

I want to save it in (**Sqlite3**)database as it is and fetch it and display on web pages using html and css.
but when i am saving it into sqlite all indentation not saving properly

Code To generate Html From Code

```
from pygments import lexers
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
formatter = HtmlFormatter(style='monokai')
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import get_all_formatters

code='''result = []
for i in range(1,11):
  if i%2 == 0:
    result.append("Even")
  else:
    result.append("Odd")
print(result)
'''
lex = lexers.get_lexer_by_name("python")
print(help(highlight))
data=highlight(code, lex, formatter)
print(data)
```

I have Tried **pygements** still no success Adding Extra Spaces After First Line
Html Pygments

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><span></span><span class="n">result</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="p">[]</span>
        <span class="k">for</span> <span class="n">i</span> <span class="ow">in</span> <span class="nb">range</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="mi">1</span><span class="p">,</span><span class="mi">11</span><span class="p">):</span>
          <span class="k">if</span> <span class="n">i</span><span class="o">%</span><span class="mi">2</span> <span class="o">==</span> <span class="mi">0</span><span class="p">:</span>
            <span class="n">result</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">append</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s2">&quot;Even&quot;</span><span class="p">)</span>
          <span class="k">else</span><span class="p">:</span>
            <span class="n">result</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">append</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s2">&quot;Odd&quot;</span><span class="p">)</span>
        <span class="k">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">result</span><span class="p">)</span>
        </pre></div>
```

Ouput of Pygments

```
result = []
        for i in range(1,11):
          if i%2 == 0:
            result.append("Even")
          else:
            result.append("Odd")
        print(result)
```

Any other way to save and retrieve python code with formatted python code

Comment: Why don't you share what errors or failures you had with pygments?

Comment: its creating single line code

Comment: How do you want to get help if you don't post the code snippet?

Comment: @jabez i have added pygements snippets check its its adding extra spaces after first line

Comment: Did you check pygments docs? I dont see you have used HtmlFormatter or anything similar to that. https://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/

Comment: yes already Created Code for that check code added

Comment: I've run your code and on my side it really looks good. Both print(data) as well as rendered html. I've checked in Chrome only.